# Sample Size Estimate of Proportion

Tags: sample-size, sample, quality-control

College admission office manually processes 1,000 applications in a month.  We want to take a sample from this 1,000 to see how many applications were processed correctly (data entry errors, typos, etc).  We estimate accuracy to be 92%.

- N = 1,000
- P-hat = .92
- Margin of error = 5%
- Confidence Level = 95%
- n = 102

From reviewing the sample size 102, accuracy is 94%, so the next time we do this monthly review, we use .94 for p-hat.  And the next time we do this review, we change p-hat to whichever value we discovered from last sample review.  Does it make sense to continually change p-hat like that?

Comment: This sounds like a great case for statistical process control.  In my opinion, you should collect data and estimate the grand mean to your desired precision.

Comment: Is there a reason you would update $\hat p$ (and thence the sample size) using only the "last sample review" rather than using the cumulative results of all previous sample reviews?